# How to pipe a list of files returned from find to cat and sort them

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to find all the files from a folder and then print them but sorted.

I have this so far

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

and it print's all files but I need to sort them too but when I do

```
find . -type f -exec sort cat {};
```

I get the next error

```
sort:cannot read:cat:No such file or directory
```

and if I switch sort and cat like this

```
find . -type f -exec cat sort {} \;
```

I get the same error the it print's the file(I have only one file to print)

Comment: Are you trying to sort the content of the files, or do you want the files sorted by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me if you want to display the contents of the files unchanged sorting the files by name, or if you want to sort the contents of each file.  If the latter:

```
find . -type f -exec sort {} \;
```

If the former, use bsd find's `-s` option:

```
find -s . -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

If you don't have bsd find, use:

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 cat
```

Comment: Note that `-z` is not a standardized option for `sort`, but is available in both bsd and gnu coreutils.

Comment: And in Busybox.

Answer (score 1):

Composing commands using pipes is often the simplest solution.

```
find . -print0 -type f | sort | xargs -0 cat
```

Explanation: you can sort filenames after the fact using `... | sort`, then pass the output (the list of files) to `cat` using `xargs`, i.e. `... | xargs cat`.

As @arkaduisz points out, when using pipes, should carefully handle filenames containing whitespaces (thus using `-print0` and `-0`).

Comment: It won't work with filenames containing whitespaces and newline.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, thanks, fixed for files containing whitespaces (but not newlines)